# Add/Remove List item from firebase using rest api

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

I am unable to add/remove items to childGroups list using firebase rest ApI.

Below is the rest api call I tried to delete the childGroup item by value, but it didn't worked. can someone please help.

Also I am not able to figure out what is the rest api to add value to childGroup.

DELETE https://moe-90cc7.firebaseio.com/subscriber/GYlSDXx0Kwh7AerOzFGf8MDmhOg1/chatGroups/GYlSDXx0Kwh7AerOzFGf8MDmhOg1-UrXBTpOMhGSTFTXRRVRmUPPzYuU2.json

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you delete a node with the REST API, you give the path of the **key** to delete. There is no `GYlSDXx0Kwh7AerOzFGf8MDmhOg1-UrXBTpOMhGSTFTXRRVRmUPPzYuU2` key under `chatGroups`, so nothing gets deleted.

The value you're looking to delete is under key `0`, so: `DELETE https://moe-90cc7.firebaseio.com/subscriber/GYlSDXx0Kwh7AerOzFGf8MDmhOg1/chatGroups/0.json`.

Note that its customary to store set-like data structure in Firebase as

```
subscriber
  GYlSDXx0Kwh7AerOzFGf8MDmhOg1
    chatGroups
      "GYlSDXx0Kwh7AerOzFGf8MDmhOg1-UrXBTpOMhGSTFTXRRVRmUPPzYuU2": true
```

This has the advantage that the groups are automatically unique and that adding the same group multiple times is an idempotent operation.

Comment: Thanks frank, I am also stuck with retrieving data from geofire. Unable to find documentation .. do you know any link with geofire and rest api calls?